# Completing code for dijkstra's code in ML

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I need help completing this code:

```
fun insertSorted(x, comp, []) = [x]
  | insertSorted(x, comp, a::rest) = ??
```

if written correctly it would return

```
- insertSorted(5, fn(a, b) => a > b, [8, 6, 3, 1]);
val it = [8, 6, 5, 3, 1]
```

The code takes a value, a comparison function, and a list and returns a new list like the one given above. Comp is used to determine what order the values in the list should be.

Comment: Since you don't say what the code is supposed to do, how do you expect someone to come with any recommendation as to how to complete it? I can kind of guess that it's a sorting algorithm and maybe Dijkstra invented it. But then what? If in doubt, I'd start by filling in characters from the ASCII table.

Comment: @Simon'ReinstateMonica'Shine I added more info to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the completion in English:

- If `x` should be inserted before `a`, the result is `x::a::rest`
- Otherwise, recursively insert `x` into `rest` and add `a` at the front of that result.

Translating into ML left as an exercise.